# Is there a quick way to install earlier Fedora kernel packages?

Tags: fedora

My laptop is behaving suspiciously (resume from sleep sometimes fails).

The problem first happened on kernel `4.8.10-200.fc28`.  But this is the oldest kernel I still have installed.  I only have the most recently 3 Fedora kernels installed.

(This is despite me having set `installonly_limit=12` in `/etc/dnf/dnf.conf` over 6 months ago, in an attempt to [keep old kernels around for longer](https://major.io/2015/05/18/keep-old-kernels-with-yum-and-dnf/).  It seems that PackageKit (or the backend for libdnf) [is just broken](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1256108).)

Is there a quick way to install older kernels for testing purposes?  (And is there any way to avoid them being removed automatically, when the next kernel update happens?)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Go the Fedora's Package Build System, called Koji, and find the kernel you are looking for here:

(edited): https://koji.fedoraproject.org/koji/packageinfo?packageID=8

> Then scroll down the the x86-64 architecture that you are looking for. Then you have two options; Either download what you need (kernel, kernel-core, maybe kernel-devel, kernel-headers, kernel-modules) to your local disc, and then use dnf to install the kernel:
>
> It would look something like: `dnf install ~/Downloads/kernel-4.6.6-300.fc24.x86_64.rpm`

The process of how to do it is described in detail in the [Fedora Magazine](https://fedoramagazine.org/install-kernel-koji/). You should not only download the package with the kernel but all three packages with kernel, kernel-core, and kernel-modules.

Comment: The process is explained in the Fedora Magazine too: https://fedoramagazine.org/install-kernel-koji/

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/186763) solution is for RHEL, but it should work the same for Fedora (in Fedora yum is link to dnf):

1. List available kernels:

   `yum list kernel*`
2. Install kernel with the desired version:

   `yum install kernel-3.10.0-693.17.1.el7`
3. Reboot the system:

   `systemctl reboot`

Comment: To avoid this being a link-only answer, could you summarize the link into this Answer?

Comment: It would be a better answer if it summarised the most important information from the linked document and then referred to the document for further information. Links have a tendency to go dead, and the answer will be useless when that happens.

Comment: It does not. There is no different kernel version available in the repos accoding to `sudo dnf list 'kernel*'`

Comment: `yum list 'kernel*'` show list of installed kernels, those on the list are already available in Grub,